# Why is the scifi.stackexchange.com data not available in Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request

When looking through the sites on https://data.stackexchange.com/, [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) isn't listed.  It's also not listed in the set of icons when writing a query.

Additionally, trying to sneak in via https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/queries/ gives a YSOD (not the Edgar F. Codd 404).

Is this intentional, and if not, can it be remedied?

Comment: This was already asked on the [Scifi meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1076/scifi-fantasy-not-on-the-data-explorer), so I'm voting to close this as off-topic

Comment: @MichaelMrozek appropriately - I looked here but not there.  Close away, MSO community!

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Not that I care to reopen this question (I blame rchern for the duplication), but I thought Meta.SO doubled as Meta.SEDE, so why is this off-topic?

Comment: @Gilles Because there's no point having it in two places, and I can't close as a duplicate of a post on meta.SFF. One could make the argument that fragmenting meta like this is a terrible idea. Not that I would ever say that, of course