# URLs containing /query or /q on SEDE for sites that don't exist throw YSOD

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, data-explorer, site-name

This was actually first mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120054/147650), but when you try to hit SEDE with the wrong database name you get a YSOD, not Edgar F. Codd, for `/q/n`, `/query/n`, `/s/n`, etc.

E.g. [first query on 'data'](https://data.stackexchange.com/data/query/1) [similar on 'dne'](https://data.stackexchange.com/dne/q/1) [first "s" on 'dne'](https://data.stackexchange.com/dne/s/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I opted not to address this back then, but since it's a rather easy fix I've gone ahead and patched it up.

Should be fixed in the next revision > 2012.9.7.6, which I'll ask about getting taken care of next week.

Comment: *"For some reason I opted not to address this back then"* - Probably so you could get reputation for fixing it at some later date. Well played.

Comment: I personally blame [someone for not following up](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=828375#828375).

Comment: How am I just now noticing that I got blamed for this?  (*Oh, right, I saw the accept on your "recent rep"*)