# Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) shows part of the web configuration file on error

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I think custom error handling is on based on the result when I visit:

> `http://data.stackexchange.com/:site/:targetsites;csv`

Is this a security issue?

Comment: Did you handcraft that url or is there a normal UI route that brings you there?

Comment: Looks some what similar to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160625/urls-containing-query-or-q-on-sede-for-sites-that-dont-exist-throw-ysod)

Comment: I guess [`RequestPathInvalidCharacters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) is defined and that could explain why you see this error before the customerrorhandler had a chance to step in. On SE proper this issue isn't present.

Comment: Those snippets aren't out of the config file - they're examples. No security issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was a security issue, you shouldn't report it on Meta. Instead, use the "[contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link.

To answer your question, no, this is not a security issue:

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application **prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely** (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

The code there is just an example for how to enable remote errors or customize the error page.

I think the error page should totally be customized, maybe with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/c#/revisions/4266).